# Read textfile into list in Applescript

Tags: file, text, applescript

I tried to create an AppleScript that reads a text file and puts the contents into a list. The file is a simple text file where every line looks like this: `example-"example"`

The first is a filename and the other is a folder name.

Here is my code now:

```
set listOfShows to {}
set theFile to readFile("/Users/anders/Desktop/test.txt")
set Shows to read theFile using delimiter return
repeat with nextLine in Shows
    if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
        copy nextLine to the end of listOfShows
    end if
end repeat
choose from list listOfShows


on readFile(unixPath)
    set foo to (open for access (POSIX file unixPath))
    set txt to (read foo for (get eof foo))
    close access foo
    return txt
end readFile
```

When I run that the output I get this:

```
error "Can not change \"Game.of.Thrones-\\\"Game Of \" to type file." number -1700 from "Game.of.Thrones-\"Game Of " to file"
```

My list looks like this: Game.of.Thrones-"Game Of Thrones" and two more lines like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is that you are trying to read the *contents* of a file (the first file you read) *as* a file.  Getting the **paragraphs** of text will break it apart at return/linefeed boundaries, which usually works better than trying to guess what end of line character(s) were used in the file.

You also don't need the whole **open for access** thing when just reading files, so your script can be reduced to just

```
set listOfShows to {}
set Shows to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/Users/anders/Desktop/test.txt")
repeat with nextLine in Shows
    if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
        copy nextLine to the end of listOfShows
    end if
end repeat
choose from list listOfShows
```

Comment: It still reads only "Game.of.Thrones-\"Game Of " in my output, i do not get any errors now.

Comment: I tried with the text: 1text, 2text ... 5text in the text file now. The result is 1text, 2text, 3text, 4text, 5. Not 5text

Comment: The script just gets each line of the file (separated by a newline character such as a return) and puts it into a list - isn't that what you asked?  Not sure why the file wouldn't be completely read, unless you are not using a plain read command and are playing around with delimiters or the number of characters read.

Comment: I just want to read every line in the file. But for some reason it can't output everything? I will try some more, you got me in the right way, thank you :)

Comment: The problem is that it only takes the 23 first characters in the text file. I don't know what can cause that?

Comment: The read command will read to the end of the file - does the text file look normal when opening in a text editor?  You might try closing and reopening the Script Editor in case there is an open file hanging around in there somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

`read` uses MacRoman by default, so it jumbles up non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 files unless you add `as «class utf8»`. (`as Unicode text` is UTF-16.)

```
paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/tmp/test.txt") as «class utf8»
```

`paragraphs of` also works with CRLF and CR line endings. This doesn't, but it ignores the last line if it's empty:

```
read POSIX file "/tmp/test.txt" as «class utf8» using delimiter linefeed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set milefile to ((path to desktop as text) & "Alert.txt")
set theFileContents to (read file milefile)
display dialog theFileContents
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript’s Language Reference states on page 120:

A series of characters beginning immediately after either the first character after the end of the preceding paragraph or the beginning of the text and ending with either a carriage return character (\r), a linefeed character (\n), a return/linefeed pair (\r\n), or the end of the text. The Unicode "paragraph separator" character (U+2029) is not supported.

So, U+8232 is ignored and AppleScript returns the whole text from the file…

U+8232 is used in TextEdit as the CR character…

Comment: While the ASLR mentions that U+2029 is not supported, it neglects to mention U+2028 which applescript also does not support. They are Paragraph Separator and Line Separator respectively. As indicated by the text, they are Unicode characters and don't seem to be well-supported except by browsers as the 8232 and 8233 entities. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Newlines.