# Applescript - open a new tab

Tags: tabs, applescript

My AppleScript abilities are rather limited, so please forgive what may be a simple question.

I have this script as an Automator Service which will open a series of aliases in new windows.
Triggered by key command in Finder via prefs>keyboard>shortcuts>services.
Service receives selected files or folders in Finder

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with aFile in input
        tell application "Finder"
            try
                set origFile to original item of aFile
                set aWindow to make new Finder window
                set aWindow's target to origFile's parent
                select origFile
            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

I'd like to try open in tabs instead, preferably without resorting to GUI scripting.
`set aWindow to make new Finder window` appears to have no equivalent `set aWindow to make new Finder tab` & scouring Apple's online documentation for 'make' or 'tab' has proven pretty fruitless... or rather much fruit, all of the wrong variety :/

I have a GUI version from another source

```
on new_tab()
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Finder"
        set frontmost to true
        tell front menu bar to tell menu "File" to tell menu item "New Tab"
            perform action "AXPress"
        end tell
    end tell
end new_tab
```

so, failing the direct approach, how could I fold this into my existing script?

MacOS 10.13.4

Comment: What is the Service's settings, i.e. **Service receives selected [_what_] in [_what_]**, and how is the **Run AppleScript** _action_ receiving its `input`, in other words, is it the first and or only _action_ or what? BTW As the research you've done didn't come up with any non **UI Scripting** method to open a `tab`, that's correct... AFAIK there is no way with _regular_ **AppleScript** to open a `tab` without resorting to **UI Scripting**. Also, what version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: @user3439894 - Extra info added to question. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the **macOS** *defaults* for both the **Open folder in tabs instead of new windows** *preference* in **Finder** unchecked, and the **Dock** *preference* **Prefer tabs when opening documents:** in **System Preferences** set to **In Full Screen Only**, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* should work as wanted with incorporating your original **AppleScript** *code* and the *code* of the `new_tab` *handler*.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set madeNewWindow to false
    repeat with i from 1 to count input
        tell application "Finder"
            if (kind of item i of input) is equal to "Alias" then
                set origFile to original item of item i of input
                if not madeNewWindow then
                    set theWindow to make new Finder window
                    set madeNewWindow to true
                else
                    my makeNewTab()
                end if
                set theWindow's target to origFile's parent
                select origFile
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end run

on makeNewTab()
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Finder"
        set frontmost to true
        tell front menu bar to tell menu "File" to tell menu item "New Tab"
            perform action "AXPress"
        end tell
    end tell
end makeNewTab
```

- On my system it was not necessary for me to use the `delay` *command* however, `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed on your system and if so, add as necessary while adjusting the *value* as appropriate.
- Coded for use in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *service* where **Service receives selected [files or folders] in [Finder]**.
- Requires **Finder** to be added to **Accessibility** under **Security & Privacy** in **System Preferences**.
- Tested under macOS High Sierra.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any other *error handling* then what's shown and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: That's the one! Seems to make no difference however I have the Dock & Finder prefs set. It gives me one new window, full of tabs to each alias... which is actually better than I thought I wanted. Great stuff, thanks.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Because the other answer was changing a _default_ setting, I mentioned those two _default_ settings because I didn't test with modified _default_ settings, only original _defaults_. Also, I didn't mention that **Finder** needs to be added to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Accessibility** because I figured you already had it added. BTW I too dislike using **UI Scripting** however it's there when another way doesn't work. Glad this can work for you. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I actually don't usually use tabs, so have that all switched off. Your solution generates tabs even with the prefs off, which is great & just what I need for this one task. I had originally tried to find a solution without UI scripting, but this hybrid seems to do exactly what I need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

### AppleScript to open Tabs in Finder from a list of paths in POSIX

Running this in the application **Script Editor** opens a predefined list of tabs from a list that one can set in normal POSIX file path, like `/path/to/folder-or-file`. To get a link to your folder or file, either press `CMD+i` or press `File->Get Info` in the menu (or just right-click on the file/folder itself). In the small window popping up, copy the path from the field named `General -> Where:` or get it from the terminal using *print working directory* (`pwd`) command and copy-pasting into the item-vars in the script below. Using a repeat loop we go through the vars included in the list and pull up one tab for each item. Very handy for those projects that use the same folders but lots of them!

```
on convertPathToAlias(thePath)
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            return (path of disk item (thePath as string)) as alias
        on error
            return (path of disk item (path of thePath) as string) as alias
        end try
    end tell
end convertPathToAlias


set item1 to "/Users/username/Desktop/myfolder1"
set item2 to "/Users/username/Desktop/myfolder2"
set item3 to "/Users/username/Desktop/myfolder3"
set item4 to "/Users/username/Desktop/myfolder4"

set myList to {item1, item2, item3, item4}

set default_path to convertPathToAlias(item1)

tell application "Finder"
   activate
   open default_path
end tell

repeat with theItem in myList

    set current_path to convertPathToAlias(theItem)

    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    delay 0.3
    tell application "Finder" to set target of front window to current_path

end repeat
```

- using the initial function `convertPathToAlias()` we convert a normal path into the Applescript alias format. Read more about [Applescript folders and files actions here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH34-SW1).
- I also added the [`delay` command](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) as the finder sometimes has an issue with loops and pulling up new tabs. At least on my machine.
- This is based off a script with static links to folders.
- To make this script import an external TXT file, check out this post on [how to turn a text file into a list and run this from that instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065087/3680335)!