# Open finder tabs on macos with python

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal

Is there a way to open **a finder window with multiple tabs** with different folders? Like you would open a web-browser with multiple tabs for sites.

Using the `open .` command in Terminal using **shell-script/bash** you can open a window to the current working directory, but using that command you ***cannot*** get *multiple tabs in one finder window*.

So how would that work?

Update:
Python's way of opening one single window, Python2.7 and Python 3, makes it possible to get [a file revealed or a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520693/3680335), like so:

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> file_to_show = "/Applications/my-sub-folder"
>>> subprocess.call(["open", "-R", file_to_show])
```

Still, no tabs involved here.

**Update, using AppleScript:** I made my own solution in AppleScript. The script uses [a pre-defined list and loops through it and opens up a new Finder Tab for each list item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70489740/3680335). List items are in POSIX format converted into the native AppleScript alias format.

If you find a solution in pure *Python*, please add it.

Comment: True, AppleScript or oascript in Automator can probably do it. But I still want to find a Python way for a set of features I hope to make in Python, perhaps translatable into other OSes also, apart from different macOS versions.

Comment: Is `finder` the real name of the file explorer software ? If so, is there a `man finder` entry ?